# Samba refuses to start with ro rootfs

Tags: linux, mount, samba, raspbian

I configured Raspbian Stretch to mount rootfs in read-only mode. 
Basically I did the following:

```
apt-get -y remove --purge triggerhappy logrotate dphys-swapfile
apt-get -y install busybox-syslogd; dpkg --purge rsyslog
rm -rf /var/lib/dhcp/ /var/run /var/spool /var/lock
ln -s /tmp /var/lib/dhcp; ln -s /tmp /var/run; ln -s /tmp /var/spool; ln -s /tmp /var/lock
```

and put this in `etc/fstab`:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults                0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults,ro             0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime,ro     0       1
/dev/mmcblk0p3  /home           ext4    defaults,noatime        0       2
tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs   nosuid,nodev            0       0
tmpfs           /var/log        tmpfs   nosuid,nodev            0       0
tmpfs           /var/tmp        tmpfs   nosuid,nodev            0       0
```

all works fine expect samba that doesn't start if rootfs is mounted in ro mode. To be sure, I temporary mounter / as rw and it started as expected.

Here the relevant part of the debug output of smbd:

```
...
Paths:
SBINDIR: /usr/sbin
BINDIR: /usr/bin
CONFIGFILE: /etc/samba/smb.conf
LOGFILEBASE: /var/log/samba
LMHOSTSFILE: /etc/samba/lmhosts
LIBDIR: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
MODULESDIR: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/samba
SHLIBEXT: so
LOCKDIR: /var/run/samba
STATEDIR: /var/lib/samba
CACHEDIR: /var/cache/samba
PIDDIR: /var/run/samba
SMB_PASSWD_FILE: /etc/samba/smbpasswd
PRIVATE_DIR: /var/lib/samba/private
...
Processing section "[global]"
doing parameter workgroup = WORKGROUP
doing parameter netbios name = MYSAMBA
doing parameter security = user
doing parameter map to guest = Bad User
doing parameter guest account = pi
doing parameter wins support = yes
pm_process() returned Yes
lp_servicenumber: couldn't find homes
get_current_groups: user is in 1 groups: 0
unix_msg_init failed: Read-only file system
messaging_dgm_ref: messaging_dgm_init returned Read-only file system
messaging_dgm_init failed: Read-only file system
messaging_dgm_ref failed: Read-only file system
```

It's pretty clear it doesn't like the read-only file system, but I don't understand what prevents it from starting. And hence how to fix it!

If I didn't provide all the information to understand the scenario, please ask me in comments!

### UPDATE

After adding the symlink for `var/lib` and `var/cache` I also symlinked `/etc/samba` to the writable partition (I don't like this, but I don't know how to symlink only `/etc/samba/dhcp.conf.new` when created).

Now the output is a bit different:

```
...
lp_servicenumber: couldn't find homes
get_current_groups: user is in 16 groups: 4, 7, 20, 24, 27, 29, 44, 46, 60, 100, 101, 108, 997, 998, 999, 1000
directory_create_or_exist_strict: invalid ownership on directory /var/run/samba/msg.lock
messaging_init: Could not create lock directory: No such file or directory
```

but:

```
$ls -l /var/run/samba
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 40 Sep 4 13:28 msg.lock
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls -dl /var/run/samba`? What (Linux) user does your samba run as?

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 340 Sep  4 17:59 /var/run/samba`. The `guest account` is `pi`, that is also the current and only user available.

Comment: On my friend's Raspbian `smbd` (a daemon) runs as `root`. If you run it as `pi` then `invalid ownership on directory /var/run/samba/msg.lock` may be because it's owned by `root`. But you said it used to work. While testing, are you sure you run samba as user it's supposed to run as?

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand your question. The `smbd.service` is started by `systemd` as `root`. `pi` is just the normal user the the `guest account` in `smb.conf`.

Comment: Saying it in other words: how would you configure samba to work with a read-only file-system? Perhaps it would be easier begin from scratch than try to guess my mistakes!

Comment: So it runs as `root`, OK. In this case ownership etc. *seems* right. Your entire approach is rather sane in my opinion. How would I do? Samba can be set to follow symlinks or not; it's a security issue and should affect shares only, I think. However I would try to avoid symlinks also in paths like `/var/run/samba/msg.lock`. You have `ln -s /tmp /var/run`; make it `tmpfs` or tell samba explicitly the lockdir is `/tmp/samba` and see if it makes a difference. This is a shot in the dark but I'm out of ideas for now.

Answer (score 0):

These lines

> ```
> LOCKDIR: /var/run/samba
> STATEDIR: /var/lib/samba
> CACHEDIR: /var/cache/samba
> PIDDIR: /var/run/samba
> ```

point to read-only locations but the server needs to write there, I think. Read [the manpage for smb.conf](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html). The respective settings are `lock directory`, `state directory`, `cache directory` and `pid directory`. *At least* these four should point to writable locations.

Comment: I added symbolic links also for `/var/lib` and `/var/cache` to `/tmp` and now those directories are writable even with the filesystem in ro. But the samba behavior is the same.